# Selenium python обход cloudflare

Tags: python, selenium, cloudflare

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium_stealth import stealth
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()




options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path="chromedriver.exe")

stealth(driver,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        )
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")


url = "https://stake.com/"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(100)
driver.quit()
```

Страница висит и дальше не идёт, кто нибудь знает как это можно решить?

Comment: ваш код не обходит cloudflare .

Comment: Я в курсе уже исправил и все работает